# OpenGL ES Coordinate System on Android?

Tags: android, opengl-es, eclipse-cdt, android-ndk, native-code

I am new to Android developing and curently I am playing arround with OpenGL ES 1 using the NDK. Unfortunetely I got a problem with the Coordinate system. In the official example, the following code is used to get the width and height of the Opengl Surface.

```
eglQuerySurface(display, surface, EGL_WIDTH, &w);
eglQuerySurface(display, surface, EGL_HEIGHT, &h);
```

Now when I want to setup  the viewport with

```
glViewport( 0, 0, w ,h );
```

and I render a quad then the quad isn't a quad, it is a deformed rectangle and centered.

How can I setup the Viewport and the Coordinate System correctly?

Answer (score 2):

You have the viewport set up correctly; you need to adjust your projection matrix (or equivalent, if you're in ES 2.0 rather than 1.x). E.g.

```
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glFrustumf(-(float)w/h, (float)w/h, -1, 1, 1, 500);
```

OpenGL makes no assumptions about the aspect ratio of your pixels or of your viewport — you have to organise yourself.

Comment: Ok thank you but how can I do that in OpenGL ES 1.x? glFrustrum is not supported in OpenGL ES 1.x.

Comment: glFrustum is part of ES 1.x, see http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/1.1/docs/man/ for documentation, http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/api/1.0/gl.h for evidence that it was in 1.0 as well as 1.1. EDIT: but there's no second 'r' in it, is it possible you're just having trouble because of a typo?